# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in html and php

Tags: php, html

I have a table in which every row have a "Buy Now" button and by clicking the button page gets redirect to paypal payment process in a new window. And i am sending data on that page like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.open('<?= base_url() ?>paypal/create_payment_with_paypal?price=<?php echo $value['price']; ?>&item_name=<?php echo $value['program_name']; ?>&item_number=<?php echo $value['id']; ?>&item_description=<?php echo $value['description'];?>&gym_id = <?php echo $this->session->userData('gym_account_id'); ?>','name','height:50;width:400')">
```

it is not working fine for every row and giving the error.please help me out how to fix it.

Comment: Try to make your ```onclick``` much simpler. Their are error(s) of conflicting **'** of JavaScript with the ***'*** of PHP in```$value['any_key']```. Also, it will be much better to not mix two languages together, try keeping PHP and JavaScript separate.  For data exchange, between the two, you can use API calls

Comment: API calls on the basis of an id??

Comment: Depending upon the situation you are in, from the code you posted, you are trying to make a payment, so using the simple an API to your PHP code, pass the values using AJAX, with some authentication obviously, this way debugging will be much easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces in your query string.  Not sure if this is leading to your issue.  But you should url encode your query string.

Currently it's very hard to debug/read.  Consider breaking up.  I've commented out the session variable here  and replaced your base_url function to test output.

```
<?php
function base_url() { return '/';}
$value        = ['price'=>'12', 'program_name' => 'physics', 'id' => '2679878', 'description' => 'day course'];
$params       =
[
    'price'            => $value['price'],
    'item_name'        => $value['program_name'],
    'item_number'      => $value['id'],
    'item_description' => $value['description'],
    //'gym_id'           => $this->session->userData('gym_account_id')
];
$query_string = http_build_query($params);
$url          = base_url() . 'paypal/create_payment_with_paypal?' . $query_string;
?>
<input type=
"submit"  value=
"Buy Now"  class=
"btn btn-success"  onclick=
"window.open('<?=$url?>','name','height:50;width:400')">
```

Output:

```
<input type=
"submit"  value=
"Buy Now"  class=
"btn btn-success"  onclick=
"window.open('/paypal/create_payment_with_paypal?price=12&item_name=physics&item_number=2679878&item_description=day+course','name','height:50;width:400')">
```